# Apache mod cache mem/disk saves the cache for 10 seconds and than re-cache

Tags: apache-2.2, disk-cache, mod-cache

I have this set up in my 000-default:

```xml
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.10:80>
    ServerName live.website.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/live.website.com
    SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
    CacheEnable mem http://live.website.com/
        MCacheSize 4096
        MCacheMaxObjectCount 1000
        MCacheMaxObjectSize 2048
    CacheDefaultExpire 3600
        CacheMaxExpire 3600
        CacheStoreNoStore On
        CacheStorePrivate On
        CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
        CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
        MCacheMaxStreamingBuffer 2097152
</VirtualHost>
```

this page `http://live.website.com/index.php` only printing : `time()`, but I see that after 10 seconds the time is re-cached.
Also tried disk, but I get the same results.

Ubuntu + lamp latest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular PHP script will need to include additional HTTP header information for `mod_cache` to work. See section "*What Can be Cached?*" from Apache's [Caching Guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html).

```php
<?php
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, max-age=3600");
header("Vary: Accept-Encoding");
echo time();
```